# Not able to detect DVD in ubuntu 16.04 . At which location DVD will display?

Tags: mount, dvd, auto-completion

Not able to find DVD which is already inserted in pc.
Kindly suggest the location where we will detect it.

Version : ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

There are some things to check...

1. Have you installed `udftools`? If not ...

   ```
   sudo apt install udftools
   ```

   `udftools` is a tool for UDF filesystems (= cd and dvd).
2. `eject -n` This should show you the device.
3. `eject` or `eject -t` should eject your DVD.
4. `sudo hwinfo --cdrom` should show you info about the DVD.

Please edit results into your question. Since this is partly a comment ... Ill remove it if it has not got a working method.

Generally ...

- DVD automatically mount in `/media/`
- In Nautilus DVD will appear in the panel on the left hand side.

Comment: I am window's user. So I don't new about it. I am using this first time. So Please tell me what is udftools?

Comment: And for installing that any code is needed?

Comment: See line 4 on what udftools is. Line 3 is an installation of udftools; it will show an error if you try to install it and it is already installed. Lines 5, 6 and 7 are commands you can type in command line.